# How to share data between express server and browser side JavaScript

Tags: javascript, express

Just simplifying my problem statement, I need to access the query params to my express route inside the JavaScript embeded inside the html that is served by express.
`

```
app.get('/some-route', (req, res) => {

  const { environment } = req.query;

  res.render("index.html");

}
```

Inside the javascript included in index.html, I need to access the environment parameter to check some further validations.